# How to remove xmlns:xsd, xmlns:xsi, xsi:type from the WCF output using XMLSerializer

Tags: wcf, xmlserializer

Using WCF Restful service with XmlSerializer I get the below response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<availabilityResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns="http://xyz.com/ABCService">
  <availabilityResult>
    <title xsi:type="Availability_1">
      <titleId>0010327457</titleId>
      <availability>
        <purchasable>false</purchasable>
        <availableCopies>0</availableCopies>
        <totalCopies>0</totalCopies>
      </availability>
    </title>    
  </availabilityResult>
</availabilityResponse>
```

(I wish to remove xmlns:xsd, xmlns:xsi and xsi:type tags)

"Availability_1" is one my derived type i used in my code. I really do not want to show this in the response.

I am using XmlSerialzer by specifying [XmlSerializerFormat] at the service contract.
WCF is able to serialize my response properly but the only issue i have is with the extra xmlns tags. Yes, I know they are useful stuff there. But, the client is interested only in the plain xml.

By looking at various posts in stackoverflow i understood i could do this by overriding few of the methods of XmlTextWriter. But the problem I have is how to let the WCF know to use my customXmlWriter (inherited from XmlTextWriter) instead of generic XmlTextWriter while serialization.

How to pass my customXmlTextWriter to the XmlSerializer which i do not have any control at this point.

I just created my data classes and defined the service contract methods from my end but did not have to do any of the serialization stuff from my side as the WCF takes care of it on its own.

Comment: I could find a working example at [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/wcf/thread/4d91994e-040f-480f-a45a-c56ce4627780). This works fine but has an side effect in my case, I have a operation contract which supports both SOAP and Restful requests. By implementing the solution referred in the above post, my Restful result comes out without any xmlns tags but my SOAP request fails. In order to fix this I have to come up with 2 contracts one each for SOAP and Rest.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different idea, but it's in the line of separation of concerns, as writing custom serialisers to actually make the responses sort of "invalid" seen from a true compliancy principe can be seen as an anti-pattern.

My idea is to develop your own IIS custom HTTP handlers and add it to the IIS processing pipeline. Doing so, will allow you to expose both the tweaked responses and the fully compliant ones.

The custom HTTP handler could use a simple XSLT to remove the required namespaces.

Have a look at this article to get started - http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework